# How to prove this alternative version of transfinite recursion

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

There are several formulations of transfinite recursion. I am interested in the following one.

Let $(V, \in)$ be a model of ZF. Let $g_1$ be a set and $G_2,G_3 : V \to V$ be two definable class functions. Then there is a unique definable class function $F : \text{Ord} \to V$ such that

$(1)$ $F(\emptyset) = g_1.$

$(2)$ $F(\alpha) = G_2(\beta,F(\beta))$ if $\alpha =\beta+1$ is a successor ordinal.

$(3)$ $F(\alpha) = G_3(F|_{\alpha})$ if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

I can prove the uniqueness thanks to transfinite induction (which is also stated in three cases) but I have some trouble with the existence. How should I define $F$ as a class of couples ?

Comment: You call this an alternative version of the transfinite recursion theorem. Do you know how to prove any version of the transfinite recursion theorem? Or even the recursion theorem for $\omega$? The idea is basically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
F&=\{\langle \alpha, X\rangle : \text{Ordinal}(\alpha) \land \exists f\,(\text{Function}(f)\land\text{Domain}(f)=(\alpha+1)\\
&\land f(0)=g_1 \land \forall \beta\,(\beta + 1 \le \alpha \implies \exists Y,Z (Y=f(\beta)\land Z=G_2(\beta,Y)\land f(\beta+1) = Z))\\
&\land\forall \beta\,(\beta \le \alpha\land\beta\ne 0\land\text{LimitOrdinal}(\beta)\\
&\implies \exists Y,Z(Y=\text{Restriction}(f,\beta)\land Z=G_3(Y)\land f(\beta)=Z))\\
&\land f(\alpha)=X)\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It seems clear that your $F$ is a function by induction but how to you prove that $F$ is defined for all ordinals ?

Comment: @user700974 By induction, of course!

Comment: Yes I guessed but for instance, how to you define your function $g$ (for $\alpha+1$) using the function $f$ for $\alpha$ ?

Comment: @user700974: If $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal, and a function $f$ exists defined all the way up to $\alpha-1$, then extend it to $\alpha$ by defining $f(\alpha) = G_2(\alpha-1,f(\alpha-1))$.  Extending a function by one pair requires only pairing and union.  If $\alpha$ is a non-zero limit ordinal, and $f_\beta$ is defined for all $\beta < \alpha$ you first show by induction that these intial segments of $f$ are compatible functions.  Then by Replacement $\{f_\beta:\beta<\alpha\}$ is a set, and then define $f_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} f_\beta$.

Comment: @user700974:  Correction, for limit $\alpha$, $f_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}f_\beta$ and extend its domain to $\alpha+1$ by setting $f_\alpha(\alpha)=G_3(\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}f_\beta)$.